# SQL Server Agent/Properties/Alert System/Mail Session/Test is disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, database-mail

In order to enable operator notifications I navigated to SQL Server Agent/Properties/Alert System/Mail Session, checked "Enable mail Profile", selected Mail System and Mail Profile. At this time Test button next to the Mail Profile was disabled, so I clicked OK and decided to return to this configuration dialog later.

This worked and notification are being sent but when I returned to this configuration dialog later the Test button is still disabled.

Can anyone explain that?

Comment: I don't have a way to _prove it_, but I _suspect_ that the `test` button would become available if you chose `SQL MAIL` (which is no longer supported) rather than Database Mail.  Naturally, you can alway test Database Mail by right-clicking that node and choosing `send test email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test button referred in the question is only available for older version of SQL Servers that supported SQL Mail. Below picture is from a SQL2008 SP4 instance where you can use the test button.

[image]

[From books online:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177418(v=sql.105).aspx)

> SQL Mail is not installed by default in SQL Server. For more
>   information, see Understanding Surface Area Configuration. SQL Mail is
>   not supported on 64-bit versions of SQL Server. SQL Mail stored
>   procedures cannot be installed on 64-bit versions.

For Database mail you can use this feature for testing.

Using SSMS, Instnace-->Management-->Database Mail-->Right click-->Sent test Email.